# Python pandas filter by date to remove all rows not containing a date in column

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel file where the data is untidy and I want to use pandas function to clean it up.

Column A (Time) contains different text - some being the time, some the Date, and others the name of a person.

```
Time
======== 
Dan
------- 
12:55
------- 
04 Oct 2019
```

So in the example, above I only want to filter by the dates - so 04 Oct 2019 would be my selection.

I thought about converting the date into a date format then just filtering by that.

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'],format='%d %b %Y')
```

But because not all rows contain a date, I get the error

> ValueError: time data '12:55' does not match format '%d %b %Y' (match)

First of all is this the best way around it to filter and if so how can I skip the non-date values for conversion?

Comment: add `errors="coerce"`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you @Serge Ballesta for comment:

> Mixing values containing only the date part and values containing only the time (hour, minutes, ...) in the same column will lead to a hard to process column...

So here is possible solution if there are 2 different formats of DataFrame, so is possible parse them separately with `errors='coerce'`, if no match is created missing value(s) `NaN`.

So is possible replace missing values by second `Series` by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html)

```
date1 = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'],format='%d %b %Y', errors='coerce')
date2 = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'],format='%H:%M', errors='coerce')

df['Time'] = date1.fillna(date2)
print (df)
                 Time
0                 NaT
1 1900-01-01 12:55:00
2 2019-10-04 00:00:00
```

For filter non datetimes filter rows with missing values after conversion in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[date1.fillna(date2).isna()]
print (df1)
  Time
0  Dan
```

Comment: Mixing values containing only the date part and values containing only the time (hour, minutes, ...) in the same column will lead to a hard to process column...